# Why login mapping on 'dbo'

Tags: sql, sql-server, principal

In database Design the user of 'fed' compared with login 'fed'.

```
USE [Design]
SELECT l.name AS login_name, p.name AS [user_name]
FROM sys.sql_logins l JOIN sys.database_principals p ON l.SID = p.SID
WHERE l.name = 'fed'
```

[image]

Why the request under login of 'fed' on the Design database select 'dbo'

```
USE [Design]
SELECT USER AS user_name
```

[image]

Comment: So when you ran that second piece of sql, were you connected as fed ?

Comment: To be honest I've no idea what select user is doing. If I wanted the user name of the current user then Select SUSER_NAME() or Select System_user would have been options.

Comment: thx SUSER_NAME() return 'fed', but why SELECT USER return 'dbo'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this first: [CREATE USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx)

You are confusing LOGIN with USER.  Your first query is inspecting LOGIN information, whereas the second is looking at USER.  Multiple LOGINs can map to a single USER, which makes things easier to manage, such as administrators all mapped to the database-owner user 'dbo'.

**EDIT**
Just to clarify, *just because* you named the column as user_name `p.name AS [user_name]` doesn't mean it is.  You're linking via sys.sql_logins, so the 'principal' that you are retrieving is the login object, who's `name` property is obviously the login name, not the `user`.

Comment: Everything appeared simply. The login 'fed' had sysadmin server role.

Comment: That would explain it, sa always maps to dbo.